# Can I be sure about the correctness of the compound nouns that I create?

Tags: compound-nouns

This is from Anne Hathaway's [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Hathaway/?fref=nf) (I saw it today):

> "What else can I say about the movie that changed my life? Thank you The Devil Wears Prada and happy 10 year anniversary!! (don't let this make you feel old- good style is eternal xx)".

I think ***ten year anniversary*** is a compound name. Using this pattern, I wrote sentences as below, although I strongly feel that I should have placed dash(s) among the words of a compound. However, consider:

- a two day infant (to imply an infant whose age is two days)
- a four month marriage (to describe a marriage that lasts four months)
- a three side negotiation ( to imply a negotiation in which there are three different groups talking)
- an eight core CPU (to describe a an [Octa-Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) CPU)
- three line road ( to describe a road in which cars moving in three lines, but in the same direction )
- three wheel vehicles (to classify vehicles which have three wheel)

I have two questions:

1. > Can we always be sure about correctness of such phrases and learn, of course, some exceptions that refute these constructions? Or these constructions are limited to few cases that we should memorize them, for example 10 year anniversary.
2. > If they are compound nouns, shouldn't it include dash(s) (-) among the words ? Personally, I think when this phrases come to being at the first time, they do include dash, but as they become commonplace English speakers omit the dash to facilitate writing the phrase.

---

It is interesting for me because, in my native language, we construct adjectives by using numbers almost in similar way. I want to organize my mind to accelerate the process of choosing words.

Comment: ten-year is a compound adjective.  Some native speakers would say *three-wheel* and others *three-wheeled*.  We say "three-way" or "three-sided" not "three side". "Tree-lined" not "tree-line road".

Comment: Dashes are merely orthographic and typographic conventions. It is writing making an attempt to express some prosodic information with semantic content.

Comment: If the adjective is one formed from the verb (passive), then it will be the past-participle, e.g. **lined**.  A road lined with trees.  **wheel** can be understood as a verb "to outfit with wheels", and that's why some people would say "three-wheeled". So too with **side**, "to be created with a certain number of sides".  A six-sided shape..

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one-arm+man%2Cone-armed+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20-%20arm%20man%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20-%20armed%20man%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Sometimes the dashes convey a lot of meaning.  Compare "man eating tiger" with "man-eating tiger"!

Comment: But few native speakers would need the crutch in the context of an actual utterance, not a mere fragment.  A maneating | man-eating | man eating tiger is on the loose.   The third one is probably not a man running down the street holding a tiger-kebab ... or a tiger kebab.

Comment: Usually there's no real confusion (there being a shortage of good tiger burger joints around).  But sometimes it's useful to help avoid ambiguity, as in the famous headline "Police help dog bite victim".

Comment: I don't disagree at all. But in the long view ( and I mean the very long view, like from runic inscriptions, ornamental inscriptions, through medieval manuscripts, early block-type, to modern-day computer screens and smartphone texting) it's clear that readers can make do with very little punctuation and even without standardized spelling.

Comment: In an example like "a two day infant" important information (age, as opposed to a period of time) is missing. You would need to say "a two day **old** infant"

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb for you to use would be to ask yourself the following question:

- If I don't include a hyphen, could people confuse this for something else?

@Stangdon's example is a great one. Having lunch with a man eating tiger is no big deal...
[image: Tiger Burger]

...but having lunch with a man-eating tiger would terrify me.
[image: A Meal To Terrify]

So if there's the possibility of confusion, throw the hyphen in there. In fact, the only times you should avoid doing so are:

- When you use adverbs that end in *-ly*, or the word *very*; such as...

  - He's a very friendly cat.
  - It's a highly efficient engine.
  - Hers is a carefully guarded secret.
- When you are talking about ages ***and*** using a plural adjective; such as...

  - There are four two-year-olds sitting in the car, but Anise is four years old.

@TRomano does indeed have a point about minimal punctuation, but personally, I'd rather have a tiger-kebab than ***be*** a tiger kebab, all things considered.

[image: Run Away! Run Away!]